# Can I use Android SDK classes in a desktop application?

Tags: android, desktop-application, bitmapfactory

I have some `android.graphics.Bitmap` data saved to a file that I want to manipulate in a desktop application.  The data is generated by a third party application, so I can't modify the app to save the data as png or jpeg.

I am wondering if I can import the android SDK jar into a java desktop project so I can use the android.graphics.Bitmap and android.graphics.BitmapFactory classes?  I have tried adding android.jar from the SDK but when I try to call the `BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray()` method I get a runtime exception ("Stub!").

Please help.

If I can't import the SDK jar, does anybody know the format of the bitmaps that android uses?

Comment: One of the problems of doing so is that `BitmapFactory` classes use native code. So you cannot just use the JAR files which contain the Java bytcode... you also need to load native libraries, which would be a PITA.

Answer (score 4):

The Android SDK is for Android's Dalvik VM, not the the normal JVM, so that is not going to work.

Since it is a bitmap, the data should be stored in a continuous list of Red, Green, and Blue pixels (the order of the colors can vary, there might also be alpha.)

So this might be an image:
[FF][00][00][00][FF][00][00][FF][00][FF][00][00]

Assuming that image was stored in RGB format and was defined as being two pixels wide (the pitch) then it would be a 2x2 px image that represented a tiny red and green checkerboard pattern.

Your app might be exporting the width/height of the image and it might not. If it isn't you'll need to determine the width in order to get a proper image.